# "Fake" a zoom level with Google Maps MapCanvasProjection

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a `google.maps.MapCanvasProjection` to calculate some things about a map (using `fromLatLngToContainerPixel`) right before it's about to be panned and zoomed to a new location. Here's how I get the projection:

```
var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function(){};
overlay.setMap(map);
var proj = overlay.getProjection();
```

However, the calculations I need to make using this overlay need to be based on the position and zoom level of the map after it's been zoomed, since it uses pixel widths that won't be accurate once the zoom level changes. I have a function I wrote called `getZoomLevel()` that returns the future zoom level I'll need, but I can't figure out how to create a "virtual map" with this new zoom level. I want to make these calculations before the actual, visible map is moved or zoomed in any way.

Short of creating an entirely new map that's never added to the DOM, is there a way to make `fromLatLngToContainerPixel` assume a different zoom level than the zoom of the currently visible map?

Working, but hackish example: http://hamclock.net/maps/

Comment: Easiest approach by far is not to overlay your sidebar. Make it a genuine "side-bar", not an "over-bar". That way, there's no need to apply an offset to give a faux center.

Comment: That would be easier, but it's not what I need. The example I linked to is a little overly-simplified, but in my actual, much larger application, there needs to be some map visible behind that bar.

Comment: Currently your sequence is (in psudocode) `map.zoom()` followed by `addListener(...map.pan())`. You may be able to reverse and adapt the opertions to give `map.setCenter()` followed by `map.zoom()`. The transitional effect will differ slightly but (with the right math) the nett result can be made identical and, if I'm right, you will avoid the need for an event listener for the second operation.

Comment: In the linked example, I have to zoom first, because the calculations in `correctCenter()` (which are needed to pan) rely on the zoom level being correct. Ideally, I'd like to be able to make those calculations before zooming, which would allow me to zoom and pan at the same time.

Comment: I think the math should be pretty trivial. If you know what the new zoom level will be, than you should be able to calculate the offset centre in advance. You may also be able to work entirely in lat/lng space - no need to convert to/from the pixel space. You will need to know the delta-lng at the equator that gives the 200px offset you require. Then, for all other latitudes, apply a `1/cos(lat)` correction. (Beware zero-divide at the poles).